# awk syntax error: syntax error at source line 1

Tags: shell, awk

The following is an example of some contents in an input file:

```
                       username: thebestusernamethereis
                    EMAILID: someemail@address.com
               enc_username: NULL
               MACHINE_CODE: NULL
                  FIRSTNAME: John
                   LASTNAME: Doe
                   ADDRESS1: NULL
                   ADDRESS2: NULL
                    COUNTRY: NULL
                       CITY: NULL
                      STATE: NULL
                      ZCODE: NULL
            ACTIVATION_CODE: NULL
             ACCOUNT_STATUS: Y
              CREATION_DATE: 2010-07-02 12:02:33
              DEFAULT_DRIVE: NULL
    EXCHANGE_BACKUP_ALLOWED: N
SYSTEM_STATE_BACKUP_ALLOWED: N
          CHECKSUM_1_METHOD: NULL
          CHECKSUM_2_METHOD: NULL
          additional_flag_1: NULL
          additional_flag_2: NULL
          additional_flag_3: F
                     USEDBY: F
             DATABASE_DRIVE: NULL
              maxquotalimit: 2147483648
              CURQUOTALIMIT: 0
             ECOMMERCE_FLAG: NULL
                      phone:
          cancellation_date: NULL
               proxy_server: sb.domain.com
                 proxy_port: 20000
          proxy_port_server: 10001
                  num_accts: NULL
                 license_cd: NULL
       IDRIVE_DEFAULT_DRIVE: NULL
international_additional_flag_1: M
            move_identifier: NULL
                  subscribe: N
                  client_ip: NULL
               USEDBY_COUNT: 0
           last_update_date: NULL
                  promocode: NULL
           password_support: NULL
          UNDER MAINTENANCE: UNDEFINED
```

I have an awk line that seems to causing the error in my script. So, I tested the line as follows:

```
cat inputfile.txt | awk '$1 ~ /^(user_name:|EMAIL:|FIRST_NAME:|LAST_NAME:|CREATION_DATE:|REGISTRATION_STATUS:)$/{printf "%s,",$2\} $1 ~ /REGISTRATION_STATUS:/{print $2\}' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

The error I receive is:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
   context is
  $1 ~ /^(user_name:|EMAIL:|FIRST_NAME:|LAST_NAME:|CREATION_DATE:|REGISTRATION_STATUS:)$/{printf >>>  "%s,",$2\ <<< } $1 ~ /REGISTRATION_STATUS:/{print $2\}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

The strange thing about this error is that the script was fine before I changed an output file name: old = IDL_$output_file.idl'; new = `$output_file.idl'. This is under PRODUCT4 above.

So, I replaced this file with a backup that was working without error messages and it is still producing this error.

I do not know what to do to resolve this. I tried changing #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash and have the same error. I do not know what the syntax error is.

I am using bash on Mac El Capitan.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: please don't expect us to go thru a 100 line script to find where the `awk` is that is causing the problem. You should be able to easily present this in a testable fashion like `echo "info ....." | awk '{broken code}'` . When you do that, you may find the source of your problem just by isolating the problem. Good luck.

Comment: I will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: @shellter I edited my question so it should be easier to work with. Thank you again.

Comment: pluse-uno for improving your Q. Please use this form for questions that  you post in the future. Generally, you'll also want to include required output and current output. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message is showing you - you have a backslash before every `}`.

Comment: Replacing `$/{printf' with `${printf' did not resolve the error.

Comment: I found it! I used sed to replace `$2}' with `$2\}'. Lesson learned. Mass editing requires review first. Next time, I will need to either extend the string I am editing to be more specific or use VIM to edit each string at a time. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have two statements on one line, with no separating semicolon.
Try adding a semicolon or newline before $1 ~ /REGISTRATION_STATUS:/{print $2}